# Do iOS BLE 4.2 enabled devices implement the secure connections protocol?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Do iOS BLE 4.2 devices implement the [secure connections protocol](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/LE-Security.aspx)?

- On the **client** side **I haven't seen any API in CoreBluetooth specific to this**.
- On the **phone hardware** side I couldn't find any publicly available document stating this.Hence I am wondering if all BLE 4.2 iOS devices support the "Secure connection" protocol at firmware level (which is apparently **optional**).

Comment: See this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204634/ios-bluetooth-ble-security-and-just-works-association-model and http://www.bluez.org/ios-8-2-introduces-le-secure-connections-support/ attempting to access an "encryption required" attribute using Core Bluetooth will trigger the bonding process. There is no explicit API in Core Bluetooth to initiate pairing/bonding

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first link refers to the table in the link that I included in the question, the second link does not specify much on iPhone devices.

Comment: No, there is nothing more explicit I have seen, but the fact that the bonding process is triggered by the attempt to access an "encryption required" attribute is a good indicator that this is BLE 4.2 encryption at work.