# Set IO capabilities for BLE pairing on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

In my use case the BLE peripheral does not have any real IO capabilities but the MITM protection is required.

As a solution the Passkey Entry pairing method is used with the 6-digit pin being exchanged via other channel. The same philosophy as with Out of Band pairing, but iOS does not support OOB, so the next best thing is to use Passkey Entry in the same ways as OOB - difference being 6-digit passkey instead of 128-bit key (better than nothing).

The problem is that for this case to work as intended, both Central and Peripheral would need to have their IO caps set to `KeyboardOnly`, which would result in `PasskeyEntry: initiator and responder inputs` pairing method.

Possible combinations, copied from *[BT Core Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) [Vol 3] Part H, Section 2.3.5.1, Table 2.8: Mapping of IO capabilities to key generation method*:

```
                    /--------------------------------------------------------------------\  
   /-----------\   /                        Initiator (iOS/Android)                       \ 
  /  Responder  \ |-------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------|
 /  (Peripheral) \| DisplayOnly | DisplayYesNo |     KeyboardOnly    |   KeyboardDisplay   |
|-----------------|-------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   DisplayOnly   |             M1             |                     M3                    |
+-----------------+         Just Works         |               Passkey Entry:              |
|   DisplayYesNo  |                            |    Responder displays, initiator inputs   |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                 |                            |          M4         |                     |
|   KeyboardOnly  |                            |    Passkey Entry:   |                     |
|                 |             M2             |    initiator and    |          M2         |
|                 |       Passkey Entry:       |   responder inputs  |    Passkey Entry:   |
+-----------------+     Initiator displays,    +---------------------+ Initiator displays, |
|                 |      responder inputs      |          M3         |   responder inputs  |
| KeyboardDisplay |                            |    Passkey Entry:   |                     |
|                 |                            | Responder displays, |                     |
|                 |                            |   initiator inputs  |                     |
+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**M1**: Not suitable as it offers no authentication, no eavesdropping protection, no MITM protection.
**M2**: Not possible because passcode which *Initiator displays* is random number generated in the iOS/Android stack and cannot be manually set.
**M3**: The same as **M2**, but in theory the BT stack on peripheral could eventually be patched to generate a "specific <s>random</s> number".
**M4**: The only way where custom passkey can be entered on both devices.

Android has [BluetoothConfigManager::setLeIoCapability](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/bluetooth/BluetoothConfigManager#setleiocapability) method for this purpose

```kotlin
import com.google.android.things.bluetooth.BluetoothConfigManager

val manager = BluetoothConfigManager.getInstance()
// Report that this device can accept keyboard user input only
manager.leIoCapability = BluetoothConfigManager.IO_CAPABILITY_IN
// TODO: Adapter needs to be restarted using BluetoothAdapter::disable() and enable()!
```

Is it possible to do that on iOS (Core Bluetooth)?

Thank you for help of any ideas!

Comment: With Bluetooth 4.2 you also have Numeric Comparison which might be an option.

Comment: A am aware of that (LE Secure Connections), however I would still need to combine this with M3 - because I in fact do not have "real time OOB key sharing" but those values are pre-entered on both sides based on some other data. So the central does not have (cannot) have any information about real-time generated random number on peripheral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question. I think M3 is as far as you can come (generate a random number on your slave which is then transferred using OOB to the user so he/she can enter the passkey on the iOS device). Other than that, you can't change the iOS behaviour. Unfortunately Apple does not provide any pairing/bonding/security API whatsoever on iOS which sucks, so you can never know if a BLE operation is "secure" or not.

If you really want security on iOS/BLE then you should have your own security layer on top of BLE (BLE is then assumed to be unsecure).

Comment: I was already thinking about application level encryption but then decided it would be easier to use already established/developed security measures. But yeah, Apple again. I will dig into M3 option and try adding some mgmt (BlueZ) command to set the password. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Note that "legacy mitm pairing" security has been known to be very broken and is not much better than just works. LE Secure Connections pairing is way better but the security protocol requires a unique passkey every time to be secure.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29338255/5616255) with the link to the [crackle](https://lacklustre.net/projects/crackle/) tool. So, do I conclude correctly that for my use case I cannot rely on BLE security if I want to be compatible with Android and iOS (that is, without OOB pairing with pre-shared keys) and be actually secure?

Comment: As I said, an iOS app can never find out if the current BLE connection is secure or not, which sucks. So yeah if you want to be sure you get secure communication you need to use your own security protocol on top of BLE.

Comment: What kind of security are we talking about then? Can you get away with something other than OOB (Specially if the peripheral is noinput nooutput)